# Why do I have a ~ file in the root of my drive?

Tags: macos, filesystem, file

I just noticed that I have a 2MB ~ file in the root of my Macbook HD. This wasn't here last time I checked (probably months ago,) and my guess is that it is from a system crash the other day or maybe from the upgrade to Yosemite.

What is this file and can I delete it without incident?

[image: finder tilde file]

[image: bash tilde file]

Comment: I just checked mine and found 2 files with ".mov" extensions. How did those videos got there I do not know. Anyway I just deleted them.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an attempt to write something to the ~ directory, but instead has been written to the file /~. This file isn't required by OS X, but if an app is still using it then deleting it could break things. Make a backup if you delete it.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to notice a file name if I `cat` the file?

Comment: @Garrett Maybe, maybe not. It's unclear exactly how the file was created and what it contains (folder structure as file or simply a file intended for a different path).